# Deleting first row and adding element to last row iny MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `message_pool` and it only has one attribute called `message`. For example:

```
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
```

I want to **delete first row** and **add** `myValue` to **last row**. I have basically two queries.

```
$query_one = "DELETE FROM message_pool LIMIT 1";
$query_two = "INSERT INTO message_pool VALUES ('$myValue');"
```

If I only run `$query_one` this result happens:

```
hello 2
hello 3
```

If I only run `$query_two` this result happens:

```
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
myValue
```

ODLY! If I first run `$query_one` then `$query_two` this result happens:

```
myValue
hello 2
hello 3
```

But I want this result to get.

```
hello 2
hello 3
myValue
```

How come it places `myValue` to the first row, but when I run the second query standalone it places `myValue` to last row?

Comment: Is it a very easy question?

Comment: Unless you specify an ORDER BY expression you will not get the consistent result.  SQL tables generally are unordered.

Comment: the problem can be solved by inserting timestamp each time when u insert. The are many ways like you can get last inserted id ( unique primary key) and increment that by one and insert that record along with id. each time you delete and insert. but while inserting make sure you get last inserted id first from db.

Comment: The question makes no sense, because you have no id or anything like that to order both queries by. There is no given that the first query will delete the row you want it to delete either. Fix your table, add an autoincrement id, a timestamp or any other way of making sure the sequence is the way you want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a primary key to your table and set it to autoincrement. It is a good practice to have primary key in every table.

```
ALTER TABLE `message_pool` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Your above query work fine after you execute above code.

Comment: I add only the primary key and I sort the list by the id when I retrieve from database. I works, thanks.